# How to merge objects while in mongo shell?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object, merge, console

I have N objects and i want to merge them.
In my case i'm sure there won't be any collisions.

I have:

```
var a = {'name': 'Freeman'}
var b = {'email': 'g.freeman@mesa.com'}
```

and i need :

```
c => {'name': 'Freeman', 'email': 'g.freeman@mesa.com'}
```

Is there a smart way to do that?

Thanks in advance!

*Trivia: I want to merge these objects while a reduce job*

Comment: Take a look at this [`link`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link posted by Anand solved my issue. Thanks!

This does what i need:

```
for (var attrname in b) { a[attrname] = b[attrname]; }
```

*source:
[How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)*

Thanks Anand!